# Metadata exposed but WSDL not found

Tags: wcf, web-services, configuration, metadata

I am having trouble with my WCF service which somehow fails to expose/publish a WSDL definition. I have already gone through the MSDN tutorial on exporting Metadata. Also have I searched at least for some hours but the majority of people have different/simpler problems than me.

I am pretty sure my config file is correct so I would be thankful for anybody who could suggest other places I can look for?

My service is generally running and I can access it on localhost, where I get the standard page for the WCF services (message displaying "To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:" etc.).

When I try to access the *?wsdl extension my browser tells me that the page couldn't be found.

When I try to test the service in soapUI it tells me that there is something wrong with the WSDL.

So, I hope this gives anybody an idea of what my problem is and I would be really thankful for any help.

Cheers

Comment: Assuming your config is correct, i assume you do have a mex endpoint setup in your config and its not using webHttpBinding

Comment: any errors in the event logs ? are you using https ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified httpGetEnabled in your serviceBehavior?

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SubscriberOperationsBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"
                       httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

You can also create a mex endpoint.

Add the following endpoint to your service configuration:

```
<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
```